# How to eliminate the blank space when using \cmidrule{} and \xcolor{} in a table?

Tags: tables, spacing

I have been struggling to find a way to eliminate the blank spaces (not colored) when using \cmidrule{} in a table.[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox,booktabs,float,multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\label{my-label}

\begin{tabular} {p{1.5cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}>{\columncolor{lred}}p{4cm}>{\columncolor{OliveGreen}}p{4cm}p{6cm}}\\\hline

\textbf{HQ {[}\%{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Preparation}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{State}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{red}\textbf{POPC}}        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{green}\textbf{DPPTE}}            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Comments}}    \\\hline                                                                                                                                                       
\multirow{4}{*}{1}                     & \multirow{2}{*}{Before rinsing}           & Non-oxidized                       & N/A                                                                                                                                                       & N/A                                &                              \\\cmidrule{3-6}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                 &                                                        & Oxidized                               & N/A                                                                                                                                                       & N/A                                 &                                                            \\\cmidrule{2-6}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & \multirow{2}{*}{After rinsing}             & Non-oxidized                       & See vesicles on surface which haven't ruptured                                                                                  & See vesicles on surface with no rupture          & I am pretty sure I was on the gold surface: vesicles were not moving and I had focused previously using BF mode                                                                                                                                                                               \\\cmidrule{3-6}                                                                                                                                                  
                                                &                                                           & Oxidized                            & See vesicles ruptured and agglomerations of "particles on surface". Cannot FRAP the background (checked to see if there is monolayer instead of bilayer). 
                                                                                                                                                                                    & See some patches, however these are not very big nor homogeneous patches. When performing FRAP photobleaching takes place and very slow recovery is seen.                                                                                                                                                                                                 & This is good hence the slow recovery, since it is much slower than on glass. However, the patches are not nice and big enough to get good enough data to be able to fit and calculate the diffusion coefficient.                                                                                                      \\ \hline


%% [rest of code]
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please note that a "MWE" needs to be a complete document that other people can use to see the issue so it only needs two or three rows but should have all the needed preamble, however basically `colortbl` does not support `\cline` or its extended version, `\cmidrule`,  from booktabs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white strips are due to the padding around rules from `booktabs`. A way to remove them is to set this padding to 0, and replace it with a padding added to top and bottom of cells by the `cellspace` package in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S`  (or `C` if you use `siunitx`):

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor} % Use colour!
    \usepackage{array, cellspace, multirow, boldline, booktabs, float}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
 \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

    \begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular} {p{1.5cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}>{\columncolor{Salmon}}S{p{4cm}}>{\columncolor{OliveGreen}}p{4cm}p{6cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{HQ {[}\%{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Preparation}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{State}} & \multicolumn{1}{Sc}{\color{red}\textbf{POPC}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{green}\textbf{DPPTE}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Comments}} \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{1} & \multirow{2}{*}{Before rinsing} & Non-oxidized & N/A & N/A & \\%
\cmidrule{3-6}
& & Oxidized & N/A & N/A & \\\cmidrule{2-6} & \multirow{2}{*}{After rinsing} & Non-oxidized & See vesicles on surface which haven't ruptured & See vesicles on surface with no rupture & I am pretty sure I was on the gold surface: vesicles were not moving and I had focused previously using BF mode \\%
\cmidrule{3-6}
& & Oxidized & See vesicles ruptured and agglomerations of "particles on surface". Cannot FRAP the background (checked to see if there is monolayer instead of bilayer).
& See some patches, however these are not very big nor homogeneous patches. When performing FRAP photobleaching takes place and very slow recovery is seen. & This is good hence the slow recovery, since it is much slower than on glass. However, the patches are not nice and big enough to get good enough data to be able to fit and calculate the diffusion coefficient. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is a nice solution, but I believe that its more aesthetic a small blank space between colored columns and horizontal rules. Just my appreciation.

Comment: Just a matter of personal taste. My opinion is that we could replace *some* midrules with white spaces, in order to make groups.